# Javascript doesn't works

Tags: javascript, html, alert

I have a code like this:

```
<select id="Prioritas" name="Prioritas">
<option></option>
<?php 
    foreach($prioritas as $item){
?>
<option value="<?php echo $item->ID_PRIORITAS; ?>"><?php echo $item->NAME_PRIORITAS; ?></option>
<?php 
}
?>
</select>
```

And in the last of html, i try to input javascript, i try to alert in document ready, but the alert is not show up. This is my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    alert('TEST');
}</script>
```

Am i wrong something, and how can i fix it?

[My code for the page in here.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/as7hjza9wz4k9c8/test.php?dl=0)

Comment: Did you load jQuery?

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: You might be missing a closing parenthesis... `});</script>`

Comment: @ןnɟuɐɯɹɐןoɯ yes, i did.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev you are right, i forget to check the error from the console. Thanks.

Comment: @Mottie yes. you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing quotes in jquery method are missing. Also Load Jquery library.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    alert('TEST');
  });
</script>

<body>

  <select id="Prioritas" name="Prioritas">
    <option></option>
    <?php foreach($prioritas as $item){ ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $item->ID_PRIORITAS; ?>">
      <?php echo $item->NAME_PRIORITAS; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
  </select>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

also add JQuery library file in your page.

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

$(function() {
   alert('TEST');
 }); // missing bracket here.....
```

Answer (score 0):

I notice you  lack of an right parenthesis.
Try this to see if it works

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    alert('TEST');
});
</script>
```

Don't forget to load jquery.